# Two proofs for ratio test

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I was reading about two different proofs of ratio test when the ration is greater than $1$:

If $L=\frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_{n}\right|}>1$, then we conclude that $\left|a_{n+1}\right|>\left|a_{n}\right|$, by definition of limit :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|a_{n}\right|\neq 0$$

But the problem is that the authors conclude :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}\neq 0$$ and then they use the nth term test, but I think it's not right and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|a_{n}\right|\neq 0$ does not imply $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}\neq 0$.

In my opinion the proof works fine if for $n>N$ the terms are all positive or they all are negative, and this is a limitation, but the second proof in more general.

---

[The other proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Ratio_Test) is that:

Assuming for $n>N$ , $L=\frac{\left|a_{n+1}\right|}{\left|a_{n}\right|}>1$, we are able to choose $\epsilon>0$ such that
$L-\epsilon>1$, using this follows:

$$\left|a_{n}\right|=\frac{\left|a_{n}\right|}{\left|a_{n-1}\right|}\cdot\frac{\left|a_{n-1}\right|}{\left|a_{n-2}\right|}\cdot...\cdot\frac{\left|a_{N+2}\right|}
{\left|a_{N+1}\right|}\cdot\left|a_{N+1}\right|>\left(L-\epsilon\right)^{\color{red}{n-N+1}}\left|a_{N+1}\right|$$

However I think it should be

$$\left|a_{n}\right|=\frac{\left|a_{n}\right|}{\left|a_{n-1}\right|}\cdot\frac{\left|a_{n-1}\right|}{\left|a_{n-2}\right|}\cdot...\cdot\frac{\left|a_{N+2}\right|}
{\left|a_{N+1}\right|}\cdot\left|a_{N+1}\right|>\left(L-\epsilon\right)^{\color{red}{n-N-1}}\left|a_{N+1}\right|$$

This is the problem I have here (the rest of the proof is easy to follow and I prevent of mentionig that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n|\ne 0$, then it is true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \ne 0$. You just need to show the contrapositive. In short
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0 \implies \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } |a_n - 0| = |a_n| < \varepsilon, \forall n>N \\
 \implies \forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \text{ s.t. } ||a_n|- 0 | = |a_n| < \varepsilon, \forall n>N \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = 0.$$

Regarding your second question, note that in the given link it takes $\epsilon$ such that $L-\epsilon>1$ (not $<$). But, as you say, the exponent should be $n-N-1$ (even if the final conclusion does not change).

Comment: Just a question, can I say that the test is applicable when the terms $\left|a_{n}\right|$ with $n>N$ are nonzero? (I mean I think this is the only thing that we should be careful about)

Comment: Yes. The ratio test is valid whenever there is only a finite set of zeros in the sequence. That is, $a_n\ne0$ for $n>N$ and $N$ large enough.